# How to understand JPA entitymanager?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have the following codebase inside a method annotated with `@Transactional`. I also have the `EntityManager` injected.

```
public Entity getEntity() {
  Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT * from table WHERE .....",  MyEntity.class);
  List<MyEntity> results = query.getResultList();

  for (MyEntity entity : results) {
    try {
      Timestamp now = ....;
      // Update the field timestamp
      entity.setTimestamp(now);
      entityManager.merge(entity);
      return entity;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

My Entity has a version field which is annotated with `@Version`. So what I'm expecting from the above codebase is for the happy path with no exceptions, only the first entity should get updated in my database. However what's happening is that all the entities get updated where the `version` field gets incremented for all of the entities.

How can I understand that?

### Update:

Part of my entity code looks like this:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value=EntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "seq_name", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_name", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long uuid;

    @Version
    private long version;

  @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @Convert(converter = TSAttributeConvertor.class)
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    public long getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(long uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

  public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }

  public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of MyEntity? And you can remove  entityManager.merge(entity);

Comment: do you have in any place something like entotyManager.setLock(OPTIMISTIC_FORCED_INCREMENT) ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli have updated the snippet with part of my entity

Comment: @osamayaccoub No, i don't do any setLock. I was hoping that hibernate will take care of optimistic locking

Comment: What does EntityListener do?

Comment: I use EntityListener to basically convert the timestamp into a String iso-8601 format. So i have another field `timestampIsoFormat` which is marked as @Transient. I followed the documentation at https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove for this.